# Chrome Extension manifest v3 hot reload

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to perform hot reload on the background (service worker)? To see any changes made to the background scripts, I have to either A) remove the unpacked extension and load it back or B) un-register the service worker.

This is quite a pain for development. Is there a way to use hot reload with v3?

Thanks

Comment: It also works to press the reload-button on [chrome://extensions/](chrome://extensions/). However, this still requires opening a new instance of the service worker's "DevTools" window, and requires more switching-around than what was possible in V2 (Pressing F5 in the DevTools window for the background page).

Comment: If you find any workaround in the meantime please share :D

Answer (score 0):

Bro, I resolved this problem in recently. I create a [repo](https://github.com/Godiswill/cra-crx-boilerplate) by create-react-app, so react-refresh can make sure that partial refresh when you are changing page. It uses [Webpack' HMR](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/#via-the-nodejs-api) and webpack.compiler.hooks to hot reload your whole crx when you are changing content scripts. By the way, zip is automatic too.

Comment: I wish someone provide English-language version of ReadMe. Google Translate ignores code snippets, for example.

Comment: Hey @godis, thanks for the repo. Unfortunately, using chrome.runtime.reload() nukes open extension pages, so does not quite do what the OP asked, which is to just reload the background service worker.